# Create migration files for LocalDB

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I am new to ASP.net core 1.0 and as I know it itself is pretty new.

I have problems applying migrations. I was following a tutorial which does the whole process written for RC1. But now as I am using RC2 and the same tutorial doesn't work.

I have updated dependencies as well as the code that you may see bellow, as well as read a lot of blog posts and videos on how to go further, but still don't understand what to do next.

I have the following code so far:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc();
    services.AddDbContext<OdeToFoodDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration["database:connection"]));
    services.AddSingleton(p => Configuration);
    services.AddSingleton<IGreeter, Greeter>();
    services.AddScoped<IRestaurantData, SqlRestaurantData>();
}

public class OdeToFoodDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Restaurant> Restaurants { get; set; }
}
```

And the following dependencies:

```
"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.InMemory": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": "1.0.0-preview1-final",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.Framework.Configuration": "1.0.0-beta8",
    "Microsoft.Framework.ConfigurationModel.Json": "1.0.0-beta4",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.PlatformAbstractions": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-beta8",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
```

The problems is that when in the command like and I run `dotnet ef` it returns the following message: "executable found matching command "dotnet-ef".

If I use dnx instead, which as I think should not work but still tried, return a "unknown keyword platform".

When checking if the local db exists with the `sqllocaldb info mssqllocaldb` command, it returns the information that it exists.

So my question is how to go further to apply migration to the project?

Comment: Does it mean you still have dnx installed? You have to uninstall dnx and all of that belongs to it (including old dnx tooling set). Then install the new ASP.NET Core tooling. https://www.microsoft.com/net/core#windows

Answer (score 0):

Had this problem as well...

The `dnvm, dnu, dnx` toolchain was replaced by `dotnet` when RC2 replaced RC1. Uninstall all `ASP.NET Core` features and make sure the only ones you have are the following:

[image: .NET Core RC2]

Install required frameworks from:
https://www.microsoft.com/net/core#windows

When you have done this, ensure that you are targeting the correct frameworks in your `project.json`. The `dnxcore50` can be targeted but is deprecated, use `netcoreapp1.0` instead but **not** `dnx451` but you can target `net451` if you need to make use of the full framework.

When you run the `dotnet ef` command, are you running it from the folder where the `project.json` is located? If not, you should.